# How to implement imageswitcher code in android application?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, imageswitcher

I want to get images name from database and images are stored in the resource folder
Could you show me how to do it.
I tried few methods but none works.

Comment: is the image already present in the resources folder? do u just have to get the name of the image from database and display the image in the imageview?

Comment: no i have to get name from database

Comment: getting image name from database is similar to getting any other record. here is a simple tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant do it, resource folder is read only folder, and the R.java also generated at compiled time, not in runtime. You can save the image in sd card or cache memory .